# ReactJS PropType to check values of associative arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm passing in an object, which is an associative array, as a prop.  I don't know the keys (property names) beforehand, I only know that the values should be strings or booleans (for example).  How can I validate this using PropTypes?

EDIT:
An example would be:

```
{
    "20161001": true,
    "20161002": true,
    "20161003": true,
    "20161004": false,
    "20161005": true,
    "20161006": false
}
```

Comment: Please give an example to your associative array

Comment: So the tricky bit is that you're not allowed to write dynamic prop types because the whole point is that you're being declarative. Your best bet would be to require `PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object)` and then do manual validation if it's super necessary.

Comment: @ZekeDroid `PropTypes.arrayOf` won't work because it's not really an array, it's a simple object used as an array with named indexes.  The keys are created at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed this again today, and found out this is supported using `PropTypes.objectOf()`.

See https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html :

```
// An object with property values of a certain type
optionalObjectOf: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.number)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can validate using React.PropTypes.
But what you can do is you can validate it in the function

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  <write your logic with what ever you want to validate or check or compute>
}
```

how ever if you want to stop the render if the validation fails, then no need of the above function, you can use the following function

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
  if(validate()){
    return true
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here's the only answer I can think of, which I don't know if it's proper React but works like you intended:

The idea is you create your object at runtime from your parent component (if you don't have one, then make one) and export it. Then import it in your actual component and construct the `propTypes` static object from it:

In your parent component file, outside the actual component:

```
function generateMyObject() {
    const myObj = {};
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].forEach(i =>
        myObj[`2016010${i}`] = Math.random() > 0.5
    );

    return myObj;
}
export const myObj = generateMyObject();
```

This will export a named object called `myObj`. Of course you add whatever logic you have. The point was to show that we don't need to know the names of the keys to do validation.

In your child component file:

```
import { myObj } from './ParentComponent';

export default class ChildComponent extends Component {
    static propTypes = Object.keys(myObj).reduce((key0, key1) => ({
        ...key0,
        [key1]: PropTypes.bool,
    }), {})

    // rest of the component logic
}
```

The first bit grabs the keys from your object, then it reduces them into a single object as you are looking to do.

Comment: That reduce operation will be executed even in production mode, right?  I don't want that since propTypes are only checked in debug mode.

Comment: That doesn't sound correct. Why would you only check prop types in develop? It's also possible that when you minify your production code, react will optimize and potentially not do the check but in my opinion selective validation is not a good idea.

Comment: And you obviously could do selective validation, with a ternary, but I highly urge you not to do that.

Comment: It's how React works.  In production mode (`NODE_ENV=='production'`), no development warnings (including PropType violations) are logged.  Why?  Performance of course.  But indeed, I'd rather not put those flags in my own code.

Comment: Then I don't see why they would appear in production mode. All the reduce function does is generate the `propTypes` object